# Import util module in multi-module spring project

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have written multimodule spring boot project having following structure.
[image]

Currently I am trying to call `utils-module` into two separate self running modules, `ingestion-service` and `alert-service`.The pom of modules are as follows:

**parent module pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.common.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>cds-monorepo-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>cds-monorepo-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <modules>
        <module>ingestion-service</module>
        <module>alert-service</module>
        <module>utils-module</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**ingestion-service pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.common.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>cds-monorepo-demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ingestion-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.common.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils-module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.common.io.Main</mainClass>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**alert-service pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.common.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>cds-monorepo-demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>alert-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.common.io.Main</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**utils-module pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.common.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>cds-monorepo-demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>utils-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I am facing following error:

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ingestion-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.common.io:ingestion-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.common.io:utils-module:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could not find artifact org.common.io:utils-module:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in snapshots (http://artifactory.abc-internal.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException**

Since module is in same repository.Why it is giving error?

**Update:**

Changing the order of modules in parent pom have no effect.its trying to download from artifactory still.

Comment: switch the order of the modules in your parent .

Comment: It is trying to download from artifactory still..not getting reason or issue? @M.Deinum

Comment: Have you tried specifying a relative path for the parent?

Comment: Can you clarify more where to mention which relative path.quite new to multimodule architecture.thanks in advance @M.Deinum

Comment: In the `<parent/>` segment, you can delcare a `relativePath` and point it to the parent pom.

Comment: One question, does this entry needs to be in utils-module or ingestion-module in which i am trying to import utils-module

Comment: all of them except the parent itself.

Comment: Can you please try first: `mvn clean` on plain command line from the root of your project (`Experimental/cds-monorepo-demo`) and post the result here...